# Select the first occurrence from the last group with common column without using LAG/LEAD

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to come up with the query that will select the first date when work was assigned to the last person, for example:

[image]

I came up with following query ([SQL Fiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=4cec51f1-c9d5-4b30-b9d8-64e116e2d39f)):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[AssignedTo]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssignedTo]
(
    [WorkId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [OwnerId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT INTO dbo.AssignedTo (WorkId, OwnerId, ValidFrom) VALUES (1, 1, '2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO dbo.AssignedTo (WorkId, OwnerId, ValidFrom) VALUES (1, 2, '2020-01-02');
INSERT INTO dbo.AssignedTo (WorkId, OwnerId, ValidFrom) VALUES (1, 1, '2020-01-03');
INSERT INTO dbo.AssignedTo (WorkId, OwnerId, ValidFrom) VALUES (1, 1, '2020-01-04');
INSERT INTO dbo.AssignedTo (WorkId, OwnerId, ValidFrom) VALUES (2, 3, '2020-01-05');
INSERT INTO dbo.AssignedTo (WorkId, OwnerId, ValidFrom) VALUES (3, 4, '2020-01-06');

;WITH AssignedToWithPrevOwner AS 
(
    SELECT
        WorkId, ValidFrom, OwnerId, 
        LAG(OwnerId) OVER (ORDER BY ValidFrom) AS PrevOwnerID
    FROM
        dbo.AssignedTo
),
DatesAssigned AS 
(
    SELECT atwo.WorkId, MAX(atwo.ValidFrom) AS DateAdded
    FROM AssignedToWithPrevOwner AS atwo
    WHERE atwo.PrevOwnerID <> atwo.OwnerId OR atwo.PrevOwnerID IS NULL
    GROUP BY atwo.WorkId
)
SELECT * 
FROM DatesAssigned;
```

The problem is that uses `LAG` function which I am trying to avoid as it hurts performance a lot. Is it possible to achieve the same without using `LAG`/`LEAD` functions?

Comment: It is *possible* using a `CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ...WHERE ... ORDER BY ...)` pattern to access each prior row, but that is likely to be more costly than `LAG()`. Assigning `ROW_NUMBER()` values, writing to a temp table, adding an index, and self-joining might also be an option, but again, I don't think you will get a performance improvement there.  This is a variation of the *gaps-and-islands* problem, and using 'LAG()` is pretty much a part of the standard solution.

Comment: Side note: I believe that you likely need a `PARTITION BY WorkId` in your `LAG() OVER(...)` expression.

Comment: Using `LAG` in itself isn't a performance issue, you should inspect the execution plan and see if you are missing indexes etc.

Comment: Please don't use images, user table markdown.

Answer (score 0):

This CTE works, but I'm not sure how it would scale with a larger dataset.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  at.WorkId
            ,at.OwnerId
            ,at.ValidFrom
            ,0 AS Lev
    FROM    dbo.AssignedTo AS at
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  cte.WorkId
            ,at1.OwnerId
            ,at1.ValidFrom
            ,cte.Lev + 1
    FROM    cte
            INNER JOIN AssignedTo AS at1 ON cte.WorkId = at1.WorkId
                                            AND cte.OwnerId <> at1.OwnerId
                                            AND cte.ValidFrom < at1.ValidFrom
)
SELECT  t.WorkId
        ,t.FirstAssignedToWorker
FROM    (
            SELECT  t.WorkId
                    ,MAX(t.MinDate) AS FirstAssignedToWorker
                    ,MAX(t.Lev) AS MaxLev
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  cte.WorkId
                                ,cte.OwnerId
                                ,MIN(cte.ValidFrom) AS MinDate
                                ,cte.Lev
                        FROM    cte
                        GROUP BY
                                cte.WorkId
                                ,cte.OwnerId
                                ,cte.Lev
                    ) AS t
            GROUP BY
                    t.WorkId
        ) AS t;
```